# transform all text on page into Lower Case

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, lowercase

I am looking for a method that transforms all text present on the page into LowerCase. I was reading an review and unfortunatelly the person has posted in all uppercase. I tried to read but all uppercase text is harder to read, not to mention it is considered shouting on the web.

I know javascript have methods such as `string.toLowerCase()` & `string.replace` But I can't figure it out.

so looking for some kind of JavaScript bookmarklet that converts all text into LowerCase on a already loeaded html page.

[Edit]

Found the solution, here javascript code to change the css style `text-transform: lowercase` for entire page:

```
var styleElement = document.createElement("style");
styleElement.type = "text/css";
if (styleElement.styleSheet) {
  styleElement.styleSheet.cssText = "* {  text-transform: lowercase }";
} else {
  styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("* {  text-transform: lowercase; }"));
}
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElement);
```

Comment: You could do it much easier: `document.body.style.textTransform = "lowercase"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are simply wanting to change html text to lowercase, you could do it with css.

```
text-transform: lowercase;
```

Would that work?

Comment: Yes, but how do I apply this on-the-fly? document.write method or something?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this to someone else's webpage? e.g. you are reading the text on their site and just want to change it to lowercase?

Comment: ^^^Yes And I have figured it out. Thanks a bunch for css idea. I was thinking in some-other direction.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of turning everything to lowercase, you could set up a bookmarklet, which when clicked, will record the position of your next click. From the position you can use the `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` method to get the actual dom node. This dom node will probably be a `<p>` tag or a `<div>` tag. Do whatever you want now!

May be an overkill though!